How to add value to mood in an mp3 file via mutagen (Python)?
I couldn't find a way to write mood to an mp3 file via mutagen (Python library)
Initializing:
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
from mutagen.id3 import ID3, TIT2, TALB, TPE1, TPE2, TCON, TPUB, TENC, TIT3, APIC, WOAR, PRIV
audio = MP3(mp3_file, ID3=ID3)

I could write the subtitle using
audio['TIT3'] = TIT3(encoding=3, text=subtitle)
Also, I could write the Author URL using
audio['WOAR'] = WOAR(encoding=3, url=author_url)
But I couldn't find a way to write the mood
I wrote the mood (Sad) manually in the file properties then ran
mutagen.File("file.MP3").keys()
and I got the result
dict_keys(['TIT2', 'TALB', 'TCON', 'TPE2', 'TPUB', 'TSSE', 'TENC', 'TIT3', "APIC:'Album Cover'", 'APIC:', 'WOAR:https://youtube.com', 'PRIV:WM/Mood:S\x00a\x00d\x00\x00\x00', 'TPE1'])
I tried many ways but couldn't get the Mood to work.
I even tried with TMOO like said in the first comment. Still didn't work.
Here is the full python code
import os
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
from mutagen.id3 import ID3, TIT2, TALB, TPE1, TPE2, TCON, TPUB, TENC, TIT3, APIC, WOAR, TMOO
from PIL import Image

def add_album_art(mp3_file, album_art_file):
    audio = MP3(mp3_file, ID3=ID3)
    if audio.tags is None:
        audio.add_tags()

    # Open album art image
    with open(album_art_file, 'rb') as img:
        audio.tags.add(
            APIC(
                encoding=3,  # 3 is for utf-8
                mime='image/jpeg',  # or image/png
                type=3,  # 3 is for the album front cover
                desc='Cover',
                data=img.read()
            )
        )
    
    audio.save()

def edit_mp3_metadata(mp3_file, title, subtitle, contributing_artists, album_artist, album, genre, publisher, encoded_by, author_url, mood):
    audio = MP3(mp3_file, ID3=ID3)

    if title:
        audio['TIT2'] = TIT2(encoding=3, text=title)  # Title
    if subtitle:
        audio['TIT3'] = TIT3(encoding=3, text=subtitle) # Subtitle
    if contributing_artists:
        audio['TPE1'] = TPE1(encoding=3, text=contributing_artists)  # Contributing artists
    audio['TPE2'] = TPE2(encoding=3, text=album_artist)  # Album artist
    audio['TALB'] = TALB(encoding=3, text=album)  # Album
    if genre:
        audio['TCON'] = TCON(encoding=3, text=genre)  # Genre
    audio['TPUB'] = TPUB(encoding=3, text=publisher)  # Publisher
    audio['TENC'] = TENC(encoding=3, text=encoded_by)  # Encoded by
    audio['WOAR'] = WOAR(encoding=3, url=author_url)  # Author URL
    if mood:
        audio['TMOO'] = TMOO(encoding=3, text=mood)  # Mood
    audio.save()

def main():
    mp3_file = input("Enter the path to the MP3 file: ")
    if not os.path.isfile(mp3_file):
        print(f"Error: The file '{mp3_file}' does not exist.")
        return
    album_art_file = input("\n(Enter to skip from now)\n\nEnter the path to the album art image: ")
    if album_art_file:
        if not os.path.isfile(album_art_file):
            print(f"Error: The file '{album_art_file}' does not exist.")
            return
    
    title = str(input("Enter the title: "))
    subtitle = str(input("Enter the subtitle (Title + Version/Type): "))
    contributing_artists = str(input("Enter the contributing artists (A semicolon and a space at the end of each artist): "))
    album_artist = str(input("Enter the album artist: "))
    album = str(input("Enter the album:  "))
    genre = str(input("Enter the genre: "))
    publisher = str(input("Enter the publisher: "))
    encoded_by = str(input("Enter the encoder: "))
    author_url = str(input("Enter the author URL: "))
    mood = str(input("Enter the mood: "))

    if album_art_file:
        add_album_art(mp3_file, album_art_file)
    edit_mp3_metadata(mp3_file, title, subtitle, contributing_artists, album_artist, album, genre, publisher, encoded_by, author_url, mood)
    print("MP3 file metadata and album art updated successfully.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Windows version info:
Edition:        Windows 10 Pro
Version:        22H2
Installed on:   21-‎02-‎24
OS build:       19045.4651
Experience:     Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.19060.1000.0

"I wrote the mood (Sad) manually in the file properties" - with which poorly designed program? By "WM" I suspect Windows Media Player which just wrote a UTF-16LE encoded text of your "Sad" instead of using ID3v2.4's TMOO right away, see https://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-frames. Look up mutagen's documentation if it supports writing generic text frames and then add your own TMOO with just any word as content that you like. Tag the Q with "id3" instead of "file".

@AmigoJack I wrote it by hand in explorer by going to file properties, not by using any program.
I also tried by TMOO

"Explorer" is drastically different in each Windows version (which you didn't mention) and has a long history of having bad metadata support over the years. I was talking about the ID3 frame TMOO - hence my link, hence my suggestion to refer to mutagen itself. Edit your Q to include the Python code you used for writing said text frame.

@AmigoJack I've updated it.

Again: Explorer is not good at metadata - if by "Still didn't work" you expected the Explorer to read ID3v2's TMOO frame (when he writes it via a PRIV frame) then you have false expectations. Look at the MP3 file being manipulated by your Python program either in a hex editor (to verify the frame's existence) or use a dedicated media player (like MPC-HC or VLC, since mutagen supports TMOO very well.

(Wants an "intense network", abandons his own question...) Why?

@AmigoJack I abandoned my project, and I left this platform for months. So, there you go. Thanks for your comments tho.
